# Recovering a deleted 128-bit encrypted .dmg file

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, encryption, data-recovery

I need to recover a recently deleted **15 GB** `.dmg` file, which was deleted from a drive which is otherwise not in use. It should be easy to recover, but neither `Data Rescue 3` nor `Disk drill` seem to find anything. I made sure `.dmg` is scanned for in the file types, but the file is not showing up after a deep scan.

How can i recover this `.dmg` file?

I'm on a Mac, the drive is an SSD (HFS+), the OS is OSX Yosemite 10.10.4

Comment: Because it’s encrypted, it is (ideally) indistinguishable from random data. You may have more luck with a program that understands HFS+ and tries to restore the deleted file entry.

Comment: Sounds feasible. Do you have any suggestions in particular, as to which program i could use?